# Plotting a function progressively with Julia

Tags: julia

I'm having a hard time doing an animation with Julia.

I have a function sf(t)=t^(1/2) going from tmin=0 to tmax=40, and I don't understand how to show the solution progressively from tmin to tmax. I have tried multiple approaches using the Julia docs and tutos I found online but they almost all use predefined functions (mainly sin and cos). The error Julia returns with the code below is `MethodError: no method matching getindex(::typeof(sf), ::Int64)`. I have two questions: **Why is this error appearing?** and **Is Ithere a simpler way to create an animation than to access indices in a loop?**

Thanks

```
using Plots
tmin=0
tmax=40
tvec= range(tmin,tmax,length=100) 

# I define the function here, but I'm not sure this is really needed
function sf(t) 
    t^(1/2)
end

# I create an "empty" plot to use it in animation
p=plot(sf,0)

# To create the animation, I do a loop over all t's present in tvec
anim = @animate for i ∈ 0:length(tvec)-1
    push!(p,tvec(i),sf(i))
    frame(anim)
end

# And finally I (try to) display the result
gif(anim,"scale_factor.gif",fps=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC the `@animate` or `@gif` macro expects a plot at the end of the loop, so you want to do something like this:

```
anim = @animate for i ∈ eachindex(tvec)
           plot(sf, tvec[begin:i])
       end
gif(anim,"scale_factor.gif",fps=30)
```

Comment: A few things to note, you can 100% `push!()` into a plot, that is how it is generally updated. Also, per the original code, it's worth mentioning that Julia uses 1 based indexing, just keep that in mind for future code.

Comment: ```julia> p = plot(sf, 0:1)

julia> push!(p, 0.5, 0.8)
([0.0, 1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 1.0, 0.8])

julia> p
Error showing value of type Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}:
```
maybe `push!()` can work but it seems utterly unstable (and confusing?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment, it works well now. However, isn't calling a new plot in the for loop more resource consuming than creating it outside and just updating it with push?

Comment: making the internal representation of a "plot" is very cheap, the heavy part is rendering it out with GR, which you will have to do any way for each "frame", there's no magic of updating the rendering in place